# How to create a parameterized job with Jenkins api

Tags: python, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am using Jenkins python api to create a parameterized job, I can create a job with one parameter using the following config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>A build that explores the wonderous possibilities of parameterized builds.</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>B</name>
          <description>B, like buzzing B.</description>
          <defaultValue></defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers class="vector"/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>ping -c 1 localhost | tee out.txt
echo $A &gt; a.txt
echo $B &gt; b.txt</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers>
    <hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
      <artifacts>*</artifacts>
      <latestOnly>false</latestOnly>
    </hudson.tasks.ArtifactArchiver>
    <hudson.tasks.Fingerprinter>
      <targets></targets>
      <recordBuildArtifacts>true</recordBuildArtifacts>
    </hudson.tasks.Fingerprinter>
  </publishers>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

What I really want is to create a job with multiple parameters, I have tried adding a paralleled `<name>` tag in this xml, but it actually make one parameter in a new job. Do I change the xml mistakenly?

What's more, is it possible to add predefined values in parameter fields in the api? For example, the parameter `B` would have a value `b` after job creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each parameter needs its own hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition section.  It sounds like you're trying to put multiple names inside one StringParameterDefintion section, which won't work.

If in doubt, create the job by hand, then go to the page for that job and append '/config.xml'.  You will get back the XML for the job.  Get your Python to replicate that, and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you, and the '/config.xml' after url trick is very helpful!

Comment: May I ask if I have a job with parameters and default values, I got `HTTP ERROR 400: Nothing is submitted` error when I build the job through python api, without parameters. I presume since the job's parameters have default values, adding the same parameter values in build request is unnecessary.